# Unable to install Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, bower

I am trying to install Git and add it to the PATH so that i can use Bower.

I downloaded the exe file from

> http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git

And when i try to execute it i get the following error. am running as an Admin.

[image]

Comment: have you tried downloading the file again? have you tried saving it somewhere else? have you tried this on another machine to check if the setup file is fine?

Comment: If you are want to use git to work with eclipse..try "egit" plugin for eclipse kepler...I am not sure this plugin works with other versions for eclipse or not..go with that..

Comment: yeah i have tried it. doesnt help :(

Comment: you might try http://www.sourcetreeapp.com and look here http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about use [this one](http://windows.github.com/)?

It's a client of github , and also provide a git shell environment